# How well do concurrent writes scale with io_uring?

Tags: linux-kernel, io, block-device, system-calls

**Background:** I'm very intrigued by the potential performance gains of `io_uring`, but I don't have enough familiarity with C, the Linux kernel, or the inner workings of block devices to implement meaningful benchmarks. I'm not looking for hard numbers, just an architecture overview that will inform my continued research.

---

Imagine that I have a program which repeatedly appends batches of ten 4-byte integers to a file and then syncs it. I want to switch to a model where I append each integer in the batch to its own file instead. That is: I'll write a single 4-byte int to each of 10 files and synchronize all of them.

Using synchronous IO, the original scheme uses 2 syscalls (1 write + 1 sync), and the int-per-file approach uses a staggering 20 (10 writes + 10 syncs). In terms of syscalls, the `io_uring` savings would be enormous: I can achieve the equivalent of 20 syscalls with a single `io_uring` submission. What's unclear to me is how the *rest* of the Linux `write` machinery will scale once the submission has occurred.

- Do most disks have some amount of hardware support for parallel writes? Or maybe SSDs do but spinning disks don't?
- Do writes get pipelined (over the bus?) to the disk so the kernel doesn't have to wait for a round-trip response for each one?
- Does the kernel itself end up queuing all of the syscalls requested via `io_uring`?
- Are there other bottlenecks I haven't considered?

It could well be that my mental model is wrong. Any pointers are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> Do most disks have some amount of hardware support for parallel writes? Or maybe SSDs do but spinning disks don't?

Nigh-on all disks do regardless of whether they are spinning or solid state (even spinning disks have caches so for small amounts of data they can appear as not too slow). Cheap USB keys or SD cards will achieve poor concurrency but there will be some level of parallelism there too... In terms of maximum parallel commands for a single device, SATA can have up to 32, SCSI tends to range from 10s to 100s, NVMe can go to the 1000s (I think the spec limits you to a maximum of 65536 but I don't know of device that goes that high yet).

> Do writes get pipelined (over the bus?) to the disk so the kernel doesn't have to wait for a round-trip response for each one?

Yes multiple writes (or reads) can be sent in parallel. However whether this happens depends on lots of things (e.g. the kernel may group them together for efficiency, synchronisation may be needed so the queue has to be drained etc)

> Does the kernel itself end up queuing all of the syscalls requested via io_uring?

Maybe. `io_uring` will complete the I/O inline if it won't block otherwise it will queued. From [Efficient IO with io_uring](https://kernel.dk/io_uring.pdf): "More importantly, for operations that will not block, the data is served inline".

> Are there other bottlenecks I haven't considered?

Yes. It's also unclear if you are doing enough I/O per second to truly see the benefit of something like `io_uring`... Additionally frequent syncs are likely to limit parallelism depending on frequency and how they are being done. If you're doing buffered I/O the kernel is wringing parallelism out even in the synchronous because you are writing to RAM then the kernel destages from RAM in parallel where possible. (Note that the previous items are not an exhaustive list)

(Question from title)

> How well do concurrent writes scale with io_uring?

OK to very well depending on which kernel you are using and how you are submitting the I/O. See the references and links in this [answer to "Is there really no asynchronous block I/O on Linux?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57451551/2732969).

### References

- [A block layer introduction](https://lwn.net/Articles/736534/) - two part series talking about the block layer
- [Linux Block IO: Introducing Multi-queue SSD Access on
  Multi-core Systems](https://kernel.dk/blk-mq.pdf)- paper describing the architecture of Linux multi-queue changes
- The [Introduction to the Linux Block I/O Layer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebHINEF6PDk) YouTube video presentation